# Sort the div sections with prices in (Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I've some problems to order the prices in a specific section. I need to order it when the document is ready, I'm trying with jQuery and JavaScript without results...
I hope someone can help me.

The HTML is something like this:

```
<div class="custom_div_prices">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="prod-price">100 €</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="prod-price">300 €</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="prod-price">400 €</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="prod-price">200 €</div>
   </div>
<div>
```

(there is the div with class "row" because there are other elements on it that I omitted since are not useful at this case).

So I'm trying to put elements in an array to order them (ASC), using str_replace removing space and currency but after it, I don't know how I can continue...
I'm new with JavaScript e jQuery, so I need to take confidence yet.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You say you are trying to use a function called str_replace. Can you please provide that code so that someone can check it and try to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are being provided some static HTML like what was provided, it might be best to parse out the prices and then rewrite the html for them and replace the html of the parent div with it. Something like this:

```
// Set up an empty array to store prices
let amt = new Array();
//Iterate all prod-price elements
$('.prod-price').each(function() {
    let price = parseInt($(this).text().split(" ",1));
    // Add the price to the array we created
    amt.push(price);
});
//sort the array of prices
amt.sort();

//create a new HTML string of all the prices
var htmlStr = "";
amt.forEach(function (val) {
    htmlStr += '<div class="row"><div class="prod-price">'+val+' €</div></div>\n';
});

//replace the contents of the parent div with the new html
$('.custom_div_prices').html(htmlStr);
```

Of course given your specific situation you will likely have to alter the code a bit.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4dfaej52/